# Storing data temporarily from a websocket callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, signalr

For the life of me i can't seem to wrap my head around getiing data stored temporarily from a websocket callback to compare with the next set of data because of its scope I'm using nodejs and the wrapper I'm using is using signalrjs

```
socket.whatever((data , client) => {
     let temporaryValue = data.feed;
     //Problem is that this keeps getting               
     //updated as it's connected
}
```

Comment: Why don't you compare first and then save the data in the variable?

Comment: I need to compare the beginning feed to the next instant data.feed but the temporaryValue is constantly being updated to the next data.feed from the websocket and i can't access it out of its scope to temporarily store it's value before the feed gets updated

Comment: try this format, 

var temporaryValue;
socket.whatever((data , client) => {
     // Compare temporaryValue with data.feed
     // After you are done, store new value
     temporaryValue = data.feed;
}

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to not have to use a database but in the end decided storing the value in a database was the best approach for me